# 'IPhoneLine' does not contain a definition for 'PhoneLineStateChenged'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-voip

I am just starting with Ozeki VoIP SDK.
in my register method, my phoneLine does not recognize PhoneLineStateChanged.
my code is below.

```
public void Register(bool registrationRequired,string displayName, string userName, string authenticationId, string registerPassword, string domainHost, string domainPort)
    {
        try
        {
            var account = new SIPAccount(registrationRequired, displayName, userName, authenticationId, registerPassword, domainHost, domainPort);
            Console.WriteLine("\n Creating SIP account {0}", account);
            var natConfiguration = new NatConfiguration(NatTraversalMethod.None);
            var phoneLineConfiguration = new PhoneLineConfiguration(account);
            //phoneLine = softPhone.CreatePhoneLine(account);
            phoneLine = softPhone.CreatePhoneLine(phoneLineConfiguration);
            Console.WriteLine("Phoneline created.");
            phoneLine.PhoneLineStateChanged += phoneLine_PhoneLineStateChanged;
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```

and my references are

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Ozeki.Network.Nat;
using Ozeki.VoIP;
using Ozeki.VoIP.SDK;
```

did I forget a reference or what?

Comment: Did you try Changed with an A rather than an E? (i.e. PhoneLineStateCh**a**nged)

Comment: What are A and E?

Comment: A is the first letter of the alphabet. E is the fifth letter of the alphabet. My point being PhoneLineStateCh**e**nged won't work because that is not how you spell changed, and the creators of the API have spelt changed the correct way (with an A).

Comment: ok this was a mistake but phoneLine does not recognize PhoneLineStateChanged too!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the SDK examples, it seems that the event is actually called `RegistrationStateChanged`. So this should work:

```
phoneLine.RegistrationStateChanged += phoneLine_PhoneLineStateChenged;
```

It's a little misleading that their example also calls it `phoneLine.PhoneLineStateChanged`. I guess they renamed it.

Comment: i have a new problem! when i run my program the program cannot run this line softPhone = SoftPhoneFactory.CreateSoftPhone(5000, 10000); and will stay running in this line!

Comment: @hassan it may be best to post a new question about that.